# Equivalency of the set of real numbers to the set of all continuous real functions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I understand that the set of real numbers is equivalent to the set of real numbers in the interval $(0,1)$ and also equivalent to the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I have seen a claim in a book that the set of real numbers is also equivalent to the set of all continuous real functions of one or several variables. However, I do not know how to think of a proof. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** A continuous function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ is uniquely determined by its values on $\Bbb Q^n$.

> Denoting $\omega:=|\Bbb Q|$ we have $|\Bbb Q^n|=\omega$, $\ |\Bbb R|=2^\omega$ and  $$|\{\text{functions }\Bbb Q^n\to\Bbb R\}|=(2^\omega)^\omega=2^{\omega\cdot\omega}=2^\omega\,.$$